# Problem to Extending Localization Sources in abp v 6.3.0

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp, react-boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I need to extend localization sources.
According to the descriptions in the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization#extending-localization-sources),
I added the localization sources files in a folder named **AbpWebXmlSource** and marked **embed**.
After that, I registered them in the PreInitialize() method of module.

```
Configuration.Localization.Sources.Extensions.Add(
    new LocalizationSourceExtensionInfo("AbpWeb",
        new XmlEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            "HMS.Core.Localization.AbpWebXmlSource"
        )
    )
);
```

But unfortunately it does not work when used. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a series of test I find the answer.
first must to added AbpWeb-fr.xml to abp.core project in any folder you want.
then need to get proprties of AbpWeb-fr.xml and convert it to embeded resource.
then must add this code to `[your]coremodule.cs` in `preinitialize()` method.

```
Configuration.Localization.Sources.Extensions.Add(
           new LocalizationSourceExtensionInfo("AbpWeb",
               new XmlEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider(
                   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                   "" //important - this line need to fill empty string 
               )
            )
        );
```